react-native-code-push updateDialog: true, but only message shown, missing header and buttons
I'm using react-native-code-push to handle updates in my React Native application. I've configured updateDialog: true in CodePush.sync() to display a dialog when an update is available, with immediate installation (installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE). However, when an update is detected, only the update message is shown without the expected header and buttons (Install and Ignore).
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import CodePush from 'react-native-code-push';
import Profile from './components/Profile';

const codePushOptions = {
  checkFrequency: CodePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL,
};

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    CodePush.sync({
      updateDialog: true,
      installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Profile />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default CodePush(codePushOptions)(App);

In this setup:
I expect a dialog with a title, update message, and buttons (Install and Ignore) to appear when an update is available.
However, only the update message is displayed without any buttons or a header.
Could someone please advise on how to ensure that the complete update dialog (with title, message, and buttons) appears correctly? Am I missing any additional configuration or handling for updateDialog?


Look at https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-create-a-confirm-dialog-in-react-native/
